# Get controller action name from a given url string in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Given a url string in Magento like "https://example.com/some-catalog/some-porduct.html" I would like to get controller, action, and router name programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

While in a view file you can get it using the following
Get controller name

```
$this->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Get action name i.e function name

```
$this->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Get router name

```
$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

When in a class file you can use Mage class to get the following

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Get action name

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Get router name

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

Hope this helps.Thanks